# Unreachable catch block for TimeoutException in WebDriver code

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have below piece of code which checks if a webpage is loaded within 1 min or not. I receive Unreachable catch block for TimeoutException. Could anybody tell me why?. Thanks

public class PageLoadedin1min {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver =new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;
    try
    {
         driver.get("http://localhost/login.do");
         System.out.println("Page Loaded in a min");

    }
    catch(TimeoutException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Page is not loaded in a min");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure you're importing the right `TimeoutException`?

Comment: Thanks!. Yes I had imported a wrong package.I had used java.util instead of org.openqa.Thanks once again